# Wordpress Primary menu not updating after reordering menu items

Tags: wordpress

In functions.php, I registered primary menu like this-

```
<?php
register_nav_menus( array(
    'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'intralink' ),
) );
?>
```

And in Homepage I have used below code:

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array(

'theme_location'    => 'Primary',
'container'         => 'ul',
'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

));
?>
```

Then after creating a menu from wordpress Menus, nothing happens? Maybe it's not drag drop problem, maybe it's something I did wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Did you associate the menu you created to the correct position in the menu manager?

Answer (score 0):

Theme location should be `'menu-1'` 
It should look like the following

```
wp_nav_menu( array(

'theme_location'    => 'menu-1',
'container'         => 'ul',
'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

));
```

Hope this will solve your issue.